# customize appearance of selection in angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Can I customize the selection in angular-ui-grid somehow?
(to be a `<input type="checkbox">` instead of a selected V)

Didn't find any documentation about this...

Comment: That's why I'm using bootstrap as css framework.

Answer (score 4):

**To modify the actual row header icons:**

You can override the template for the selection row header buttons and add custom class css. Inject templateCache in your controller and override the template like this.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionRowHeaderButtons',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected , 'ui-grid-icon-cancel':!grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity), 'ui-grid-icon-ok':grid.appScope.isSelectable(row.entity)}\" ng-click=\"selectButtonClick(row, $event)\">&nbsp;</div>"
  );
```

The template uses a method in your controller scope to identify whether the row is selectable.

Sample plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/vaqBY235Lfz7WLvy0FCc?p=preview

Comment: Awsome! The thing is I meant for it to be a `<input type=checkbox`. How can I achieve that? (edited the question after re-reading it - your understanding was perfect, still can you assist :))?

Comment: This example just shows that you can override the template for the header. You will have to modify the div to have your checkbox and associate with row selected property.